# Reasonable ways to implement depth-first iterator for a hierarchical (nested) data structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers

I have a data structure that boils down to nested containers:

```
struct ComplexContainer {
   struct Item {};
   std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Item>>> _containerMadness;
}
```

Now I want to implement a depth-first forward iterator. My initial idea was:

```
struct const_iterator {
        const_iterator& operator++();
        const IndexedFragment& operator*() const;

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Item>>>::const_iterator _lvl1Iterator;
    std::vector<std::vector<Item>>::const_iterator _lvl2Iterator;
    std::vector<Item>::const_iterator _lvl3Iterator;
};
```

But then `operator++` is **way** too difficult to implement because it's not guaranteed than level 1 container is not empty, in which case lvl 2 and lvl 3 don't even exist. Similarly, lvl 2 container may exist but be empty. Since `std::vector::iterator` doesn't hold a user-accessible reference to its container, I don't see a simple way to check for that (there's no `iterator.valid()` or some such). I understand that it can be implemented with all the sanity checking, but I don't like the code it results in - neither its structure nor the amount.

There must be a neat way to do this!

Comment: Why don't you make a template function that applies a visitor? The default, or the "basic" case is when the input is just an `Item`. Then you write a specialization for `std::vector<T>` which recursively applies the visitor to each element of the `std::vector`. In case of a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` this will do the same visitation order as your depth-first multi-level iterator.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Okay, "Visitor", that's a pattern I haven't heard about in years (and never used it myself). Great Google entry point, thank you.

Comment: A n-ary tree is simpler to handle

Comment: @DieterLücking: isn't that what my structure already is? What do you have in mind?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: So, having just googled it myself to see what turns up, (I was curious), I remember looking at many of those links long ago and finding it fairly abstract OO theory and not that helpful. If you want a concrete understanding of what I meant by visitor, check out the documentation of `boost::variant`, and esp. `boost::apply_visitor`.

Comment: Isn't it the best if you implemented a vector<vector<T>> iterator in terms of a vector<T> iterator, then a vector<vector<vector<T>>> iterator in terms of a vector<vector<T>> iterator? Or maybe a vector^n in a generic manner..